# Kendo UI grid not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to bind my KendoUI grid and I am getting a 500 server error in the console. The only thing I can think of is that it doesn't like "@(Html.Kendo().Grid()" but intellisense does not error out. Does it seem like something is setup wrong with my project? Any advice would be greatly appreciate. Below is what I have in my controller and Index.cshtml page.

```
        public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request) {
        using (var ctx = new DataEntities()) {
            IQueryable<Customer> customers = ctx.Customers;
            DataSourceResult result = customers.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result);
        }

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataLibrary.Customer>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Phone);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Fax);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Website);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customers"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your Customer_Read method work ok?
Is the result variable populated with the results of the search?

Try adding AllowGet property.

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I am going to try that when I get home. When I go to /Customers/Customers_Read it errors and when I googled the error people said add AllowGet. Should it error out when i try to browse to my Customers_Read action? Would the demos on the telerik website really be wrong?